# cURL POST request to Java SpringBoot api returns Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, curl, post

I have built an API following the spring.io tutorial and the get request to list all entries works fine but when I try to make a POST request with cURL to add an entry it gives me this error:

```
"error":"Unsupported Media Type"
```

This is the post request code in the Java app:

```
  @PostMapping("/employees")
Employee newEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee) {
return repository.save(newEmployee);
}
```

The cURL command for POST that I am using is:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080/employees -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"name": "Samwise Gamgee", "role": "gardener"}'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this to your PostMapping:

```
consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

Comment: I added and same error

Comment: strange...that usually works for me - perhaps amend your header to match exactly this -> -H "Content-Type: application/json" (you have there lower t and not using space after :)

Comment: I put upper case T and space and same error

Comment: It worked I put instead on single ' i put double '' and i put \ in the keys and values like: curl -X POST localhost:8080/employees -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"name\": \"Samwise Gamgee\", \"role\": \"gardener\"}"